# How to embed an image with rounded corners in svg

Tags: svg

I want to embed an image with rounded corners inside a svg-file. how can i aproach this? I googled about that problem, but couldnt find anything useful...
I'm grateful for any help or hints.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<svg width="640" height="800">

    <rect x="280" y="0" ry="10" width="80" height="100"
    style="fill:limegreen; stroke:black;" />

    <rect x="260" y="90" ry="15" width="120" height="30"
    style="fill:mintcream; stroke:black;" />



    <rect x="200" y="150" ry="10" width="80" height="100"
    style="fill:limegreen; stroke:black;" />

    <rect x="180" y="240" ry="15" width="120" height="30"
    style="fill:mintcream; stroke:black;" />


    <rect x="360" y="150" ry="10" width="80" height="100"
    style="fill:limegreen; stroke:black;" />

    <rect x="340" y="240" ry="15" width="120" height="30"
    style="fill:mintcream; stroke:black;" />



    <rect x="120" y="300" ry="10" width="80" height="100"
    style="fill:limegreen; stroke:black;" />

    <rect x="100" y="390" ry="15" width="120" height="30"
    style="fill:mintcream; stroke:black;" />


    <rect x="280" y="300" ry="10" width="80" height="100"
    style="fill:limegreen; stroke:black;" />

    <rect x="260" y="390" ry="15" width="120" height="30"
    style="fill:mintcream; stroke:black;" />


    <rect x="440" y="300" ry="10" width="80" height="100"
    style="fill:limegreen; stroke:black;" />

    <rect x="420" y="390" ry="15" width="120" height="30"
    style="fill:mintcream; stroke:black;" />

</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

the greens are supposed to be different images. so how do i get the images to have rounded corners?

Comment: clip the image to a clipPath that is a `<rect>` element with rx and ry set

Comment: well, i want to insert several images in one svg-image. so i have to define for each image one unique clippath?

Comment: Show the code you have already and what you want it to achieve.

Comment: i edited now my first post and inserted the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply the same clipPath to multiple elements like this...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<svg width="640" height="800">

    <clipPath id="clip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
        <rect ry="0.1" width="1" height="1" fill="black" />
    </clipPath>

    <rect x="280" y="0" width="80" height="100"
    style="fill:limegreen;" clip-path="url(#clip)" />

    <rect x="260" y="90" ry="15" width="120" height="30"
    style="fill:mintcream; stroke:black;" />



    <rect x="200" y="150" width="80" height="100"
    style="fill:limegreen;" clip-path="url(#clip)" />

    <rect x="180" y="240" ry="15" width="120" height="30"
    style="fill:mintcream; stroke:black;" />

</svg>

</body>
</html>
```